# Using power automate - creating random pairs of people from an excel table and emailing them

Tags: power-automate, microsoft-flow

I have an excel file on OneDrive with a list of employees, and I want a flow that every monday creates pairs of people which are emailed with the simple suggestion that these two people get together for coffee.

The point is for people to get to know eachother, so pair creation should be random, but they need not be tracked - if some people meet for a second time that is fine.

If the number of people is odd, a random person can simply be dropped from the list each week.

I have no experience with PA, I have managed to retrieve the excel and generate emails, but the shuffling of rows and pair creation confuses me. I have asked chatGPT with no good solution provided from there.